# Gatsby Script API Not Loading Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby v4.25.3 and I'm trying convert the loading of some third party scripts to the new `<Script>` tag. I've converted the load of three Bootstrap related files in my `html.js` file:

```js
import { Script } from "gatsby";

import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <noscript key="noscript" id="gatsby-noscript">
          This app works best with JavaScript enabled.
        </noscript>
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
        <Script onLoad={() => console.log("success")}
          onError={() => console.log("sadness")} src="/bootstrap.min.js" />
        <Script onLoad={() => console.log("success")}
          onError={() => console.log("sadness")} src="/jquery.min.js" />
        <Script onLoad={() => console.log("success")}
          onError={() => console.log("sadness")} src="/popper.min.js" />
        <div id="recent-comments" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
        <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html:
            `.form-preview {
            display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      }`}} />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any errors/warnings/log entries in the browser console for any of the files. Looking in the network dev tab I also don't see the files being requested. The files are served correctly if I manually request them.

I've looked at the documentation and don't see what I'm missing:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting them in any other file/component rather than the `html.js`?

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
        <Script onLoad={() => console.log("success")}
          onError={() => console.log("sadness")} src="/bootstrap.min.js" />
        <Script onLoad={() => console.log("success")}
          onError={() => console.log("sadness")} src="/jquery.min.js" />
        <Script onLoad={() => console.log("success")}
          onError={() => console.log("sadness")} src="/popper.min.js" />
      {children}
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
};

export default Layout;
```

To me, it looks that the strategy of adding it in the `html.js` collides with the `postBodyComponents` (or any other [`onRenderBody` parameters](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#onRenderBody)) and with the rehydration of the custom `html.js`

Comment: thank you! That solved it, I was unaware of that interaction.